# JavaScript. Что лучше сделать в этой ситуации?

Tags: javascript

Люди помогите. Хотел бы понять, как на чистом js написать функцию, которая будет возвращать все двухзначные числа из неотсортированного массива в отсортированный, где будут только двухзначные числа. Просто не совсем понимаю, как это лучше реализовать. Не судите строго, я новичок в js.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для новичка из массива перегнать в другой массив:

1. Создать пустой массив, куда будет складываться результат
2. Сделать цикл по массиву с числами, и если число больше чем 9 и меньше, чем 100, то складываем в результирующий массив.
3. Отсортировать итоговый массив можно либо методом пузырька либо любым другим способом: https://academy.yandex.ru/posts/osnovnye-vidy-sortirovok-i-primery-ikh-realizatsii  , + https://habr.com/ru/post/335920/

- Сортировка "пузырьком" (как раз для новичков)
- Сортировка вставками
- Сортировка посредством выбора
- Сортировка перемешиванием (шейкерная сортировка)
- Сортировка расчёской
- Сортировка выбором
- и т.д.

---

Для более продвинутого уровня:

1. Для выборки можно использовать метод **[filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**  для отсева лишних данных, по тому же принципу, что описан выше в пункте №2
2. Для упорядочивания есть метод **[sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**

Comment: Плюсик) Хороший ответ.

Comment: Спасибо огромное вам за отличный ответ, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Сделать цикл по массиву с числами, и если число больше чем 9 и меньше, чем 100, то складываем в результирующий массив.